# UIKit/UIKit.h not found for clang building Mac Catalyst

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst

I'm building a static iOS/macOS library for Mac Catalyst, using the following flags:

```
clang \
  --target=x86_64-apple-ios13-macabi \
  -isysroot /Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
```

This builds vanilla source files, but fails with:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

Since TARGET_OS_IPHONE is defined, it looks like the target flag is working. However, UIKit/UIKit.h is not found, even though it's in the SDK:

```
$ find -L /Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -name UIKit.h
/Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Versions/A/Headers/UIKit.h
/Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/UIKit.h
/Applications/Xcode_11.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h
```

Do I need to explicitly specify the UIKit framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double-secret build settings to make this work are:

```
FAT_LIB_MAC_CATALYST_FLAGS = -arch x86_64h \
 --target=x86_64-apple-ios13-macabi \
 -isysroot $(MACOSX_SDK_DIR) \
 -isystem $(MACOSX_SDK_DIR)/System/iOSSupport/usr/include \
 -iframework $(MACOSX_SDK_DIR)/System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks
```